# Error message when searching an array, incompatible data types

Tags: java, arrays, jgrasp

I am currently getting error code

TOOLS.java:48: error: incompatible types: ToolItem[] cannot be converted to int[]

when running this program that extends from a .class.

The issue is with the line

```
int indEX = SearchArray(toolArray, srchnum);
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. The only thing I can think of is toolArray contains information about tools from the ToolItem class, which has Strings as well as integers and doubles, for storing tool information like name/ID/quantity etc. I'm not sure where I went wrong. I can post the .class if needed

```
public class TOOLS extends ToolItem
{
   // Private members
   private int numberOfItems;
   private ToolItem[] toolArray = new ToolItem[10];

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   public TOOLS()
   {
      int numberOfItems = 0;

      for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      toolArray[i] = new ToolItem();


   }

   // search method
   public static int SearchArray(int[] toolArray, int srchnum)
   {
      int i=0;
      while (i < toolArray.length)
      {
         if (toolArray[i] == srchnum)
            return i;
         else
            i++;

      }
      return -1;

   }

  // calling search method
  public void main(String[] args)
  {
      int srchnum;
      System.out.println("Enter a toolID to search: ");
      srchnum = keyboard.nextInt();
      int indEX = SearchArray(toolArray, srchnum);


      if (indEX == -1)
         System.out.println(" " + srchnum + "No ID match");
      else
         System.out.println(" " + srchnum + "was found at " + indEX);   

  } 
}
```

Comment: Well, look at the type of the `toolArray` variable, and then look at the method signature for `SearchArray`, then consider the call `SearchArray(toolArray, srchnum)`. Now look again at the error message, and you should see what it's trying to tell you...

Comment: method signature says first argument should be `int[]`. but what you're passing is `ToolItem[]`. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Well you declared `private ToolItem[] toolArray = new ToolItem[10];` but you're calling a function that asks for an `int` array:

`public static int SearchArray(int[] toolArray, int srchnum)`

Based on your code it would seem that you're trying to search by index in the array? You could change the parameter of the function you're calling and then use the `getIndex()` method on the specified array to compare the index with the `srchnum`.

---

```
//Changed first parameter type
public static int SearchArray(ToolItem[] toolArray, int srchnum)
{
  int i=0;
  while (i < toolArray.length)
  {
     //Get the index of the toolArray at position 'i'
     if (toolArray[i].getIndex() == srchnum)
        return i;
     else
        i++;

  }
  return -1;
}
```